# How to implement Angular directive to show modal when navigating to another page in the site?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using an angular directive to alert the user of unsaved changes if they try to close the tab or browser.  Now, I want to add a condition to that directive where if it is a url change within the site, to trigger a custom modal. Is it possible to store the code for this modal in the directive template so that I don't have to copy it to the bottom of each view?  Here is my directive so far:

```
.directive('confirmOnExit', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
        window.onbeforeunload = function(){
          if ($scope.currentForm.$dirty) {
            return "You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave the page?";
          }
        }
        $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
          if ($scope.currentForm.$dirty) {
            $scope.showModal = true;
          }
        });
      },
      template: "<div id='myModal' class='modal-background' ng-show='showModal'>
                  <div class='modal-window'>
                    <div class='modal-text-container'>
                      <div class='modal-text'>You have unsaved changes. Do you still want to continue?</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='btn-container btn-group'>
                      <button type='button' class='btn btn-teal' ng-click='yes()'>Yes</button>
                      <button type='button' class='btn btn-blue' ng-click='no()'>No</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>"
    };
})
```

And the HTML:

```
<form name="currentForm" ng-model="currentForm" confirm-on-exit>
   <input type="text" ng-model="input1" />
   <input type="text" ng-model="input2" />
   <input type="text" ng-model="input3" />
   <input type="text" ng-model="input4" />
   <input type="submit" ng-click="saveChanges()" />
</form>
```

Comment: I guess you need $compile: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to not store the code in the directive. There are multiple ways to achieve it and the here is the cleaner way of achieving this.

Define a global controller either in `<html>`, or `<body>` tag so that it's scope is available throughout your app and do the following in that global controller:

```
myApp.controller("GlobalController", function($scope) {

    // Avoid scope inheritance problem
    $scope.globalData = {}

    $scope.showMyModal = function () {
        $scope.globalData.showModal = true;
    }

    $scope.hideMyModal = function () {
        $scope.globalData.showModal = false;
    }
});
```

Now in your main HTML (like `index.html`), put the controller and that template:

```
<body data-ng-controller="GlobalController">

    <!-- other content -->

    <div id='myModal' class='modal-background' ng-show='globalData.showModal'>
        <div class='modal-window'>
            <div class='modal-text-container'>
                <div class='modal-text'>You have unsaved changes. Do you still want to continue?</div>
            </div>
            <div class='btn-container btn-group'>
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-teal' ng-click='yes()'>Yes</button>
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-blue' ng-click='no()'>No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And there is two problems with your directive. Modified directive looks like:

```
myApp.directive('confirmOnExit', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                if ($scope.currentForm.$dirty) {
                    return "You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave the page?";
                }
            };

            $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
                if ($scope.currentForm.$dirty) {
                    $scope.showMyModal();
                    event.preventDefault();         // this is required
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The first problem was that you have to use `restrict: 'A'` since you are using the directive as attribute directive and you have to mention `event.preventDefault();` otherwise your state navigation will not be prevented.

Now, we are calling that `showMyModal` method in the directive and that will be accessible since the directive's scope will inherit it's parent scope and so on.

The another way you could achieve the same using `$on` and `$broadcast` to pass the message.